# Adding a new Text to textView instead of setting the text in java FX

Tags: text, javafx, textview

I want the textview to add more line of code instead of changing/seting the text. The code below get called by a loop. The problem is only the last player's average score gets shown because the code changes the text per increment in loop and doesn't add the text below the previous text. I want each players average score to be displayed on the next line.

```
    int average = playerTotalScore.get(player)/getRowSize();
    textArea.setText(player + " average score: " + average);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read out the current text value, append and set it:

```
String content = textArea.getText() + "\n" + player + " average score: " + average;
textArea.setText(content);
```